# how to watch multiple akka actors for termination

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have akka system which is basically two producer actors that send messages to one consumer actor. In a simplified form I have something like this:

```
class ProducerA extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Produce => Consumer ! generateMessageA()
    }

    ... more code ...
}

class ProducerB extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Produce => Consumer ! generateMessageB()
    }

    ... more code ...
}

class Consumer extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case A => handleMessageA(A)
        case B => handleMessageB(B)
    }

    ... more code ...
}
```

And they are all siblings of the same akka system.

I am trying to figure out how to terminate this system gracefully. This means that on shutdown I want `ProducerA` and `ProducerB` to stop immediately and then I want `Consumer` to finish processing whatever messages are left in the message queue and then shutdown.

It seems like what I want is for the `Consumer` actor to be able to watch for the termination of both `ProducerA` and `ProducerB`. Or generally, it seems like what I want is to be able to send a `PoisonPill` message to the `Consumer` after both the producers are stopped.

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-monitor-akka-actor-death-with-watch-method

The above tutorial has a pretty good explanation of how one actor can watch for the termination of one other actor but not sure how an actor could watch for the termination of multiple actors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution I ended up going with was inspired by [Derek Wyatt's terminator pattern](https://gist.github.com/derekwyatt/3370370)

```
val shutdownFut = Future.sequence(
  Seq(
    gracefulStop(producerA, ProducerShutdownWaitSeconds seconds),
    gracefulStop(producerB, ProducerShutdownWaitSeconds seconds),
  )
).flatMap(_ => gracefulStop(consumer, ConsumerShutdownWaitSeconds seconds))

Await.result(shutdownFut, (ProducerShutdownWaitSeconds seconds) + (ConsumerShutdownWaitSeconds seconds))
```

This was more or less exactly what I wanted. The consumer shutdown waits for the producers to shutdown based on the fulfillment of futures. Furthermore, the whole shutdown itself results in a future which you can wait on therefore being able to keep the thread up long enough for everything to clean up properly.

Answer (score 2):

An actor can watch multiple actors simply via multiple invocations of `context.watch`, passing in a different `ActorRef` with each call. For example, your `Consumer` actor could watch the termination of the `Producer` actors in the following way:

```
case class WatchMe(ref: ActorRef)

class Consumer extends Actor {
  var watched = Set[ActorRef]()

  def receive = {
    case WatchMe(ref) =>
      context.watch(ref)
      watched = watched + ref
    case Terminated(ref) =>
      watched = watched - ref
      if (watched.isEmpty) self ! PoisonPill
    // case ...
  }
}
```

Both `Producer` actors would send their respective references to `Consumer`, which would then monitor the `Producer` actors for termination. When the `Producer` actors are both terminated, the `Consumer` sends a `PoisonPill` to itself. Because a [`PoisonPill` is treated like a normal message in an actor's mailbox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#poisonpill), the `Consumer` will process any messages that are already enqueued before handling the `PoisonPill` and shutting itself down.

A similar pattern is described in [Derek Wyatt's "Shutdown Patterns in Akka 2" blog post](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/howto.html#shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2), which is mentioned in the Akka documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

class Producer extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => println("Producer received a message")
  }
}

case object KillConsumer

class Consumer extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case KillConsumer =>
      println("Stopping Consumer After All Producers")
      context.stop(self)
    case _ => println("Parent received a message")
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    println("Post Stop Consumer")
    super.postStop()
  }
}

class ProducerWatchers(producerListRef: List[ActorRef], consumerRef: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  producerListRef.foreach(x => context.watch(x))
  context.watch(consumerRef)
  var producerActorCount = producerListRef.length
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Terminated(x) if producerActorCount == 1 && producerListRef.contains(x) =>
      consumerRef ! KillConsumer

    case Terminated(x) if producerListRef.contains(x) =>
      producerActorCount -= 1

    case Terminated(`consumerRef`) =>
      println("Killing ProducerWatchers On Consumer End")
      context.stop(self)

    case _ => println("Dropping Message")
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    println("Post Stop ProducerWatchers")
    super.postStop()
  }
}

object ProducerWatchers {
  def apply(producerListRef: List[ActorRef], consumerRef: ActorRef) : Props = Props(new ProducerWatchers(producerListRef, consumerRef))
}

object AkkaActorKill {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("AkkaActorKill")
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

    val consumerRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Consumer], "Consumer")
    val producer1 = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Producer], name = "Producer1")
    val producer2 = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Producer], name = "Producer2")
    val producer3 = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Producer], name = "Producer3")

    val producerWatchers = actorSystem.actorOf(ProducerWatchers(List[ActorRef](producer1, producer2, producer3), consumerRef),"ProducerWatchers")

    producer1 ! PoisonPill
    producer2 ! PoisonPill
    producer3 ! PoisonPill

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    actorSystem.terminate
  }
}
```

It can be implemented using **ProducerWatchers** actor, which manages producers killed, once all the producers are killed you can kill the Consumer actor, and then the ProducerWatchers actor.

Comment: huh -- is there some way to wait on the poison pills working based on futures instead of just waiting some arbitrary amount of time?

Comment: So you meant to say wait for one producer to die before the next?

Comment: well what if it just takes more than the sleep time for the poison pills to work through the system and all the actors to die properly?

Comment: Unless producers are dependent on each other I agree with you. But until all the producers are dead, the consumer may not die actually.